# What is the actual use of Array.ConvertAll compared to e.g. looping through the array via foreach?

Tags: c#, arrays, converters

My question is rather generally phrased, therefore, I will not provide any code (unless someone wants me to add it, but I think my question is clear enough).
I have been looking at two articles now about the Array.ConvertAll method and cannot for myself find a direct use of it.
The articles I read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx

"Converter" (Bottom of article): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117611/Delegates-in-C-Attempt-to-look-inside-Part-4

Now I understand how the converter works and how it can be used, however, I don't see the direct necessity of it. Since the actual method of how one object is to be converted into the other, has to be fully determined (e.g. in the codeproject link the method "ConvertToPersonInfo" or the arroding Action/Lambda type delegate), is it not just possible to declare and instantiate the new array of the new objects and do a foreach-loop over the old array of the old objects and copy the desired variables within that loop?

According to the Microsoft article, the old array is not effected in any way, so the final effect will not be different.

Am I missing a point here and didn't understand the Converter, or is it really just the same?

Comment: I simply asked if there is any difference. Of course if there is only the simplicity issue then it is okay, my question is rather if there is any more important use to it.

Comment: Posed as a thought question. Hope you didn't take it as a poke.

Comment: In terms of "there is any more important use to it", any tool that allows you to express the "what" in place of the "how" is better because (a) it's less prone to mistakes (off by one errors in loops etc) (b) it's easier to understand on first glance because complexity is hidden. It'll make for easier debugging and, later on, easier maintenance. In my mind, very important.

Comment: I guess that is actually one of the best answers directly.
Thinking of it as a simplification for either later maintenance or for the case that some other person actually starts using your code, the direct hiding of the complexity is important.

Comment: Other languages and libraries use the `Array.ConvertAll` style of working with arrays extensively. For example, the usual conventions in Ruby recommend using `Array#map`, which is similar to `ConvertAll`, and related functions instead of for loops altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can do it yourself. It's just a method that simplifies the conversion by creating the array and doing the looping for you.

For example:

```
 int[] newArr = new int[oldArr.Length];
 for (int i = 0; i < oldArr.Length; i++) {
   newArr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(oldArr[i]);
 }
```

vs. just:

```
 int[] newArr = Array.ConvertAll(oldArr, Convert.ToInt32);
```

Comment: Maybe it just seemed a little bit complicated as the exmaples in my articles used custom classes and therefore the Convert-methods had to be fully determined by the user.
Using Convert.ToInt32 as in your exmaple does make it easier of course.

Answer (score 3):

The end result is less typed code and a very clear statement of what you're doing. I am converting this collection to that collection (and I know that by just reading the method name) instead of having to inspect the body of a foreach loop to see what's going on.

Comment: Okay, thank you, after reading about it, it just seemed like a bit of "something you might not directly need" to me. In my opinion it is not that much more difficult to use a foreach loop, at least not for a single use.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more reusable, if you need to use it in several places in the code. However, I would think implementing it yourself could be faster in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @SystemDown I was thinking that you wouldn't want to make a method call to convert each value. I'm skeptical that the compiler would inline that in some optimization. If you know more, let me know.

Comment: The efficiency is actually an interesting point and might in the case of a very long array be useful if the conversion includes a lot of data that has to be moved.

Comment: I tested it, but interestingly Array.ConvertAll(oldArr, Convert.ToInt32) was faster than just doing for(...) and newArr[i] = (int)oldArr[i];

Comment: Well, I was rather thinking of a custom class that contains say 20 variables and the looping over a few thousand of those objects, each time copying the variables into a new custom object. I might try that tomorrow, for now I need to sleep...

Comment: @phil13131 Probably, as the custom method becomes more complex, the amount of time to invoke the method becomes less significant. But, then again ConvertAll was somehow faster. So I'm still pondering

Comment: I could imagine, the way .NET implements the included delegates must be in certain ways optimised, also in terms of efficiency.